# Calling context.getApplication() too early?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, tomcat, mojarra

I want to "test load" some composite controls (xhtml) when my webapp starts up.
But, when I try to get the Application context (getApplication()) I'm encountering this:

```
IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory
```

BTW, when I remove the call to getApplication(), the webapp works fine. So I don't think the other stackoverflow threads related to having mixed faces libraries is my issue.

Question/Help:

- **I think I'm calling getApplication() too soon?!?**
- **When should I be able to call it during my one-time initialization?**

Explanation:

I'm using Eclipse(Mars)/Tomcat(8)/Mojarra(2.2.0).
My code is currently a simple JSF page with a Java bean which ultimately loads a cached configuration within a static initialization block. So when I start debugging my one JSF page in Eclipse, Tomcat starts up, my static initializer kicks in and loads all my "plug in" information. When it tries to call "context.getApplication()" I get the "IllegalStateException Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory" exception.

My bean class has a static initializer which refers to my ENUM factory static values. This is my ENUM factory for values (I use some tricks for static init in my ENUM, but I think the issue is still that I'm calling getApplication() to early):

```
public enum CvcConfigEntities {
    THING1(EntityType.TYPE1),
    THING2(EntityType.TYPE2);

    private static final class StaticBlock {
        private static final String extPropertiesClassPathFmt = CvcConfig.EXT_PROPERTIES_CLASS_PATH_FMT.getValue();
        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CvcConfigEntities.class);
        private static final Properties properties = CvcConfigReader.getProperties();
        private static final Hashtable<EntityType, Hashtable<String, ExtensionDescriptor>> entityTypeExtensionDescriptorsByCode = new Hashtable<>();
        private static final Hashtable<EntityType, List<ExtensionDescriptor>> entityTypeExtensionDescriptorsList = new Hashtable<>();
        static {
            readConfiguredDescriptors();
        }
```

It finally funnels down to this code that tries to load the composite component:

```
public static UIComponent loadCompositeComponent(String taglibURI, String tagName, String id) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    Application app = context.getApplication(); // <--- here

    ViewHandler viewHandler = app.getViewHandler();
    String rootViewId = context.getViewRoot().getViewId();
    ViewDeclarationLanguage viewDeclarationLanguage = viewHandler.getViewDeclarationLanguage(context, rootViewId);
    UIComponent composite = viewDeclarationLanguage.createComponent(context, taglibURI, tagName, null);
```

Bigger stack trace:

```
SEVERE: Critical error during deployment:
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:449)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.getAnnotatedClasses(ConfigManager.java:507)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.processAnnotations(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:402)
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory.
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379)
        at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:140)
        at com.aadhoc.cvc.common.jsf.CompositeComponentLoader.loadCompositeComponent(CompositeComponentLoader.java:13)
        at com.aadhoc.cvc.extensions.ExtensionLoader.loadCompositeComponent(ExtensionLoader.java:30)
        at com.aadhoc.cvc.extensions.ExtensionLoader.checkExtensionDescriptor(ExtensionLoader.java:13)
        at com.aadhoc.cvc.common.config.CvcConfigEntities.readDescriptor(CvcConfigEntities.java:135)
        at com.aadhoc.cvc.common.config.CvcConfigEntities.readDescriptors(CvcConfigEntities.java:89)
        at com.aadhoc.cvc.common.config.CvcConfigEntities.access$2(CvcConfigEntities.java:80)
        at com.aadhoc.cvc.common.config.CvcConfigEntities$StaticBlock.readConfiguredDescriptors(CvcConfigEntities.java:40)
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored and fixed the problem.

It appears that my factory with static initializer was being called too early in the application lifecycle.

I refactored the code into a `@ApplicationScoped` bean with a `@PostConstruct` for initialization, and the sequencing is now working fine. When the application starts, and Tomcat is ready, it then does my initialization. I also allowed myself a `load()` method on the class that a console-based application can call so it wouldn't have to rely on the JSF `@PostConstruct`.

```
@ManagedBean(name="extensionsBean")
@ApplicationScoped
public class ExtensionsBean {
    private final ExtensionsConfig extensionsConfig = new ExtensionsConfig();

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        extensionsConfig.load(new ExtensionJsfValidator());
    }
```

I was clearly thinking more about "application initialization" rather than an application scoped bean with its own initializer.